# Visual Studio C++ looks for non existent obj, link1104

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build-error

I was programming for a while, so I decided to get up and take a break. And obviously windows thought that this would be a good time to restart my computer without asking. The problem was, when I got got back to visual studio, (I had added some custom filters before the restart), it deleted those filters and some obj files I had to store some 3D models on. Those files were then sent to the "Source files" filter. This is where the problem came up. Because I had an object called Camera, visual studio created an obj for that. However, because I had a 3D model called "Camera", visual studio used that. I deleted that file, and now visual studio only looks in the wrong directory for a file. When I try to build the project, I get this: "LNK1104 cannot open file 'Camera.obj'". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you do a [Build] ~> [Clean Solution]?

Comment: Yeah. It still does the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the code file for errors. Linking errors could be there if it is unable to compile due to some errors in the .cpp file.